# Focal statistics using geodesic distance in ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, coordinate-system, spatial-analyst, focal-statistics

I need to compute focal statistics (sum, mean etc.) for raster data spanning the whole globe. I want to use a constant radius e.g. 100km around each cell.

However the data are geographic (WGS84), so setting a radius in map units will result in the geodesic size of this radius changing with latitude.

I've written a little python script to crunch the numbers by re-calculating the filter width with every latitude to keep the geodesic radius constant, but this is slow & a bit inelegant.

Can anyone suggest a better way of doing this in ArcGIS Desktop?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  As a new user be sure to take the [Tour] to learn about the site and its protocols.  By asking how to do the same thing in either of 2, 3 or more products you are effectively asking multip-le questions which makes this too broad.  Please use the [edit] button beneath your question to focus your question on one or other.  I recommend asking about the one you are most likely to use.  You can always ask about the others in separate questions.

Comment: If your concern is to keep a constant radius, you might want to try an equal area projection.